# Can't properly reset environment variables

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

My PATH environment variables are all messed up for some reason and I simply cannot properly export and save my old presets. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. Most shortcuts won't work from the terminal. Everytime the computer shuts down, the PATH env variables disappear. Example:

```
user@user:~$ subl
Command 'subl' is available in '/snap/bin/subl'
The command could not be located because '/snap/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
subl: command not found
```

I've been reading similar questions in Ask Ubuntu and tried pretty much all the solutions proposed in the comments: export PATH, editing ~/.profile, /etc/environment, etc. These solutions bring a temporary solution, since closing the shell will reset it again, and going sudo su and back to the user will also reset the env variables.

Output of `usr/bin/env -i PS4=' $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO: ' /bin/bash -lixc true |& /bin/grep PATH`

```
  /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh:6: export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.:/snap/bin
  /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh:6: PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.:/snap/bin
    /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:110: PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.:/snap/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
    /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:110: PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.:/snap/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
    /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:110: PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.:/snap/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
    /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:110: PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.:/snap/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
    /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:110: PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.:/snap/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
    /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:110: PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.:/snap/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
    /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:110: PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.:/snap/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
    /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:110: PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.:/snap/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
    /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:110: PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.:/snap/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
    /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:110: PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.:/snap/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
    /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:110: PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.:/snap/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
    /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:110: PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.:/snap/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
    /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:110: PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.:/snap/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
  /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh:3: export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
  /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh:3: PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
 /home/user/.profile:21: PATH=/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

I need some help, can someone offer me a clue to definitively solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Add the output of `/usr/bin/env -i PS4=' $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:   ' /bin/bash -lixc true |& /bin/grep PATH` to your question, please.

Comment: Can someone help me?